# Load a dicom file with cornerstone js from an S3 bucket in AWS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dicom

I need to load an image from a dicom file stored in an S3 bucket in AWS. I am using cornerstone js with reactjs.

I know how to load the images from my local directory, but I dont know how to retrieve them from the cloud. I have looked for solutions, but non of them have worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [cornerstoneWADOImageLoader](https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstoneWADOImageLoader) to load the DICOM image into the cornerstone viewer.

This will allow you to use a URL to load the DICOM file
You can check the example here by directly pasting the link from your AWS S3, just make sure that CORS is enabled and it is accessible in AWS: https://rawgit.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstoneWADOImageLoader/master/examples/wadouri/index.html

The example source code can be found here: https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstoneWADOImageLoader/blob/master/examples/wadouri/index.html

Comment: I got an alert that said Object Object

Comment: that is the link for the dicom img

Comment: I copied the link you have to the example I sent you and it loaded successfully. Please remove the link to the DICOM file as it contains PHI

Comment: Thank you very much, I think you saved my life hahahahah